# CKEditor toolbar using wrong icon file (via Rails "rich" gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor via the 'rich' gem for Ruby on Rails.

It has historically worked fine, but at some point my editor icons started looking like this:

[image: wrong-offset icons]

I'm not sure what caused was, whether I upgraded something or what.
(I *do* know that it's ***not*** a browser-cache issue.)

**How I can fix these icons?**

## The code:

This is the HTML for the Bold button's `span` element (whitespace added for readability):

```
<span class="cke_button_icon cke_button__bold_icon"
    style="background-image:url(http://localhost:5000/assets/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=E4KA);
      background-position:0 -24px;
      background-size:auto;">
  &nbsp;
</span>
```

And the styles as interpreted by Chromium:

[image]

In that last line, `url(icons.png)` actually resolves to `http://localhost:5000/assets/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png`

## What I can see but don't know how to resolve:

There are two different `icons.png` files at play here:

1. `<gem_path>/vendor/assets/images/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png`
   (works correctly with background-position offset -24px)
2. `<gem_path>/vendor/assets/images/ckeditor/skins/moono/icons.png`
   (is calibrated for a different offset value)

In the code snippets, you can see that the CSS specifies offset -24px, thus the first image is the correct one.  The inline-element style specifies the first image, but is overridden by an `!important`-ified `url(icons.png)` which loads the second image (which is wrong).

Why the heck is it doing that?

Can I somehow fix this without forking the gem?  (I *can* fork the gem, but I'd rather not maintain a separate fork if possible.)

Comment: There's no SO tag for the `rich` gem as far as I can tell.  If I'm mistaken, please add it or let me know.

Comment: I ended up forking the gem and fixing the image, which fixed my immediate problem.  Blech.  If anyone has an actually *good* solution, please let me know.

Comment: Did you finally find a proper solution for that? It started to happened also to me recently and I have no idea what is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Add below CSS in the application.html.erb file

```
.cke_ltr .cke_button_icon {
    background-image: url('/assets/ckeditor/plugins/icons.png?t=H5SC') !important;
}
```